# Nested route gives 404 not found on a fastify app with file based routing

Tags: fastify

I've created an app with `fastify generate` but nested routes are giving me 404. `index.ts` works a directory but anything else I add is not found. I have `/a/b/index.ts` which works but `/a/b/c.ts` which doesn't. But if i move `c.ts` to the parent dir, it's detected. And i have `fastify.get('/c'...` on `c.ts`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastify is about security, so you need to check the plugins' documentation you are using under the hood.

In your case, you must change the `app.ts` file like so:

```js
  void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
    maxDepth: 4, // default is 2
    options: opts
  })
```

by doing this, [`fastify-autoload`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-autoload) will search for nested folders deep to 4 levels.

Then you will be able to call: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/a/b/c/c` assuming you created `src/routes/a/b/c/c.ts`

Comment: Thanks. BTW the doc doesn't mention at all that the default is 2 for `maxDepth`.

Comment: Now i have the issue that the file is scanned but fastify thinks it's on the parent directory...

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean? Is it like the `c.ts` file is on the `b/` folder? What is the behaviour?

Comment: It worked when I restarted the server. Thanks for your help!